# How do I specify the name of a Python package import?

Tags: python, import, pip, package

I have a python package `fmdt-python` that anyone can install with `pip install fmdt-python`. I want to configure this package so that I can call `import fmdt` anywhere. Despite my best efforts, after successfully installing `fmdt-python` python can't actually find the package `fmdt`.  How do I configure the project.toml of my pypi project `fmdt-python` to be imported as `fmdt` in python?

For reference, the pypi package `ffmpeg-python` is imported in python as `ffmpeg` We can inspect the local path pip uses to install packages to see that there is a long versioned name of the package alongside a shorter name used in the import statement:

[image]

but for my package `fmdt-python` pip only installs the directory with the long name:
[image]

I would like to configure my package so that pip installs the proper `fmdt` folder alongside `fmdt_python-0.0.12.dist-info`.

I am using `hatchling` as the build system and use a `pyproject.toml` file to configure this package. For reference, [here's](https://github.com/ejovo13/fmdt_scripts) the github of the package and [this](https://pypi.org/project/fmdt-python/) is the pypi index.

Comment: In ffmpeg's case, `ffmpeg-python` is the name of the [_distribution_ package](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/glossary/#term-Distribution-Package). That's something you always specify with your build system's metadata. `ffmpeg` is the name of the [_import_ package](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/glossary/#term-Import-Package), which is generally determined by the name of a directory in your source tree.

Comment: Yeah turns out it had to do with where I placed my config files and what I was considering the root of the python package (wrt my git repo...). The thing is the name of my source tree was indeed `fmdt`. Not an easy thing to google and it was never explicitly mentioned in any of the beginner tutorials for posting to pypi. Anyways, stumbled through my first package distribution and I got to learn more about the python ecosystem!

Answer (score 1):

The "problem" with my directory structure is that I had a python package `fmdt` in which I placed all of the configuration files like `pyproject.toml`, `LICENCE`, `setup.py`, etc.

Rearranging the structure to:

[image]
with the config files outside of the `fmdt` folder, I was able to configure my build to make the `fmdt` package available for import when downloading the pypi distribution `fmdt-python`

[image]